# converse thinking to create 3d model from given "UV unwrap image" or design drawing

Tags: modeling, uv, uv-image-editor

Assume that we already have the cloth "UV unwrap image" – so-called design drawing.

[image]

How to create a 3d model where the unwrapped UV images must exactly fit the given design drawing?

There maybe two approaches,but I don't know if they will work.

1: create a 3d model beforehand then unwrap its uv.

2: the "converse thinking" – compositing the design drawing to make a 3d model.

The question is how to make sure the models unwrapped UV image shapes exactly fit the given design drawing?

Any ideas? Many thanks.

Comment: Is it a vector? You could try manually entering path node X and Y values into vertices to make the separate parts. It'd be a pain, though.

Comment: @seaturtle,thanks for reply.  the "pain" is the why i ask for help.

Comment: so i want to find a way to process this automatic.
"vertex group","node editor","compositor distort image","shrinkwrap modifier" or something else maybe could offer help for this.but i don't know which is the right way   :(

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure there is a right way. (: Although I just remembered that you can import SVGs as curves—try doing that and then converting the curves to meshes.